# Automatic height of UICollectionView header according to contents

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I've put a header (`UICollectionReusableView`) in the `collectionView` my storyboard. Inside this header is a `UILabel`. How would I automatically adjust the height according to the contents of the label?

Comment: I am looking for an answer, too. =.=